# "Destination Host Unreachable" error after a brief interruption of the network cable

Tags: networking

Here is the situation: I had a Linux computer cluster which was connected in the private local area network, and the OS was CentOS 7.5 with v3.10 kernel. One day I accidentally unplugged the ethernet cable on one of the computers and quickly plugged it back in, but then I found that I could neither ping other computers from this one, nor vice versa. I just got the "Destination Host Unreachable" error.

The cable is currently firmly plugged in, but the prorblems have not dispeared. I had tried restarting the network service and even restarting that computer, but neither worked. I dont't believe that the cable was damaged so easily. I have made trials on other computers in the cluster and is sure that the trigger is just unplugging and replugging of the ethernet cable.

Here is the configuration file in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=eno1
UUID=b5727a1c-9c4f-46f4-b54d-988eff6e2b48
DEVICE=eno1
ONBOOT=yes
NETBOOT=yes
IPADDR=10.10.10.101
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
ZONE=trusted
```

Here is the output of `ip addr show eno1`:

```
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6c:92:bf:fa:d9:da brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.10.101/24 brd 10.10.10.255 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 12.12.12.201/24 brd 12.12.12.255 scope global eno1:0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6e92:bfff:fefa:d9da/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Here is the output of `ip route show`:

`10.10.10.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.10.101`

And here is the result of `ping 10.10.10.100`

```
PING 10.10.10.100 (10.10.10.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.10.10.101 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

This is the first 10 packets I got from tcpdump for the `eno1` interface. And `mu02` is the hostname for `10.10.10.101`. `mu01` is the hostname for `10.10.10.100`:

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eno1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
22:34:11.758062 ARP, Request who-has mu01 tell mu02, length 28
22:34:12.408319 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 8001.04:31:10:83:5c:00.8002, length 43
22:34:12.760044 ARP, Request who-has mu01 tell mu02, length 28
22:34:13.762044 ARP, Request who-has mu01 tell mu02, length 28
22:34:14.412066 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 8001.04:31:10:83:5c:00.8002, length 43
22:34:14.764062 ARP, Request who-has mu01 tell mu02, length 28
22:34:15.766045 ARP, Request who-has mu01 tell mu02, length 28
22:34:16.095625 DTPv1, length 38
22:34:16.098088 Loopback, skipCount 0, Reply, receipt number 0, data (40 octets)
22:34:16.413602 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 8001.04:31:10:83:5c:00.8002, length 43
```

I would really appreciated if anyone could provide a reasonable solution!

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Please don't post text output as images. I'd suggest [editing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/736991/edit) the question to replace them with the actual output enclosed in code brackets `{ }`.

Comment: If you do an `arp -a` do you see any other neighbor computer on the network?

Comment: I tried the command `arp -a`, and I saw only one computer `mu01 (10.10.10.100) at <incomplete> on eno1` while there should be more computers in the cluster. And I could not connected the computer `mu01`.

Comment: I have the feeling this is something layer 1 (cable/physical) or layer 2 (data link) related on the OSI model. Would it be possible to start a tcpdump on the specific interface to see what is happening?
Do you have a managed or an unmanaged switch?

Answer (score 0):

```
22:34:14.412066 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 8001.04:31:10:83:5c:00.8002, length 43
22:34:16.095625 DTPv1, length 38
22:34:16.098088 Loopback, skipCount 0, Reply, receipt number 0, data (40 octets)
```

There is a switch sending Rapid Spanning Tree Protocol packets and also Dynamic Trunking Protocol packets. There also seems to be a loopback test of some sort. This suggests that there is probably at least one managed switch in the network segment, although it may or may not be the one you are connecting the computer to.

If your system is connected directly to a managed switch (Cisco I presume?), then that the switch port might not be optimally configured. You should contact the person responsible for configuring the switch and try troubleshooting the problem together: the switch's logs or other diagnostic features should provide information on the current state of the port as the switch understands it, and comparing that port to other ports that are working well might reveal something useful.

For optimal performance, you can often tell a managed switch whether each switch port is intended to be used as an *access port* (= for plugging a computer into, sometimes also called "leaf port" when you think of the network segment as a tree graph) or as a *trunk port* (= as a link between two switches, or a switch and a router).

If this is not specified, a port can act as an "anything port", but then after a computer (or other device) connected to the switch port activates the link, the switch will take a while to attempt to figure out if this port is connected to another switch or not, and if it is, whether various advanced features will need to be negotiated between the two connected switches. This can make such an "anything port" slow to start.

If the switch as "address hijacking protection" or other security options enabled, and the computer is randomizing its MAC address for privacy (as the newest OSs may opt to do, particularly on wireless networks), these features can interact poorly: the switch decides "You are not the same MAC as before, so someone may have unplugged a legitimate system and plugged a rogue one in its place. I'll disable the port for now and let the network administrator figure out what is going on."

Comment: You are right. My computers are connected with each other through a switch.  Everything was working fine until I unplugged one computer's Ethernet cable from the switch. Though I plugged the cable back in , I could never make that computer connect with others. Could this be related to the identification of the MAC address you mentioned?

Comment: Depends on what features the switch has and how the switch is configured. If it is a managed switch with security features, and the security features are enabled in the strictest possible mode, it definitely could be related. Another possible feature that can confuse older NICs is Energy Efficient Ethernet (EEE for short); if the switch has it, try turning it off for the port. Also, see what `ethtool eno1` has to say about the state of the network interface - and `ethtool -i eno1` to identify the driver used.

Comment: I found that the MAC address of the disconnected computer remained the same as before, and the output of the `ethtool' command was also the same as on other computers. Anyway, I may still need to check the configuration of the switch.